# Where did i go wrong in my argument proving mean value theorem for functions with domain $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: real-analysis

This is a theorem in a basic analysis text.

> Let $\{c_n\}$ be a sequence of complex numbers.
>
> Let $R$ be the radius of convergence of $\sum c_n x^n$($x\in \mathbb{R}$). Then,
>
> (1) For any $0<\epsilon<R$, $\sum_{n=0}^m c_n x^{n}$ converges uniformly to some $f$ on $(-\epsilon,+\epsilon)$
>
> (2) $f$ is differentiable on $(-R,+R)$
>
> (3)$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n c_n x^{n-1}$ on $(-R,+R)$

I wanted to extend this theorem from $\mathbb{R}[X]$ to $\mathbb{C}[X]$.

And a proof for this i know, strictly depends on the mean value theorem.

So i tried to extend the mean value theorem to a function whose domain is a closed disk in the complex plane. And below is how i formulated it.

> Let $c$ be a complex number and $a,b\in B(c,\epsilon)$ be distinct elements.
>
> Let $f:\overline{B(c,\epsilon)} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that f(a)=f(b).
>
> Assume $\forall y \in B(c,\epsilon)$, $\lim_{x\to y} \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ exists.
>
> Then, $\exists t\in (0,1)$ such that $\lim_{x\to p} \frac{f(x)-f(p)}{x-p} = 0$ where $p=at+(1-t)b$.

This seemed trivially true, but the last part of my proof gives an awkward result:

Define $g(t)\triangleq f(a+ \frac{b-a}{|b-a|}t), \forall t\in [0,|b-a|]$.

Fix $z\in (0,|b-a|)$

Let $q=a+ \frac{b-a}{|b-a|}z$.

Let $A= \lim_{x\to q} \frac{f(x)-f(q)}{x-q}$

Then, it can be shown that $\lim_{t\to z} \frac{g(t)-g(z)}{t-z} = \frac{b-a}{|b-a|}A$.

Since the right hand side may be complex and left hand side is a real valued function, this result doesn't seem true to me. (Even though the limit is taken w.r.t the topology on $\mathbb{C}$.)

Where did i go wrong?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Mean Value Theorem for complex analytic functions?

Comment: A real-valued holomorphic function is constant. Your assumptions imply $A = 0$, and that is correct.

Comment: To expand on what @DanielFischer said, by assuming both complex differentiability *and* the condition that $f(a) = f(b)$, $f$ real valued, you have essentially assured yourself that you must have a constant function, (which turns out to be zero). The mean value theorem for complex analytic functions is a bit different than the mean value theorem for real functions, and quite weird. It says that for any analytic function in some region $B$, $f(a)$ is equal to the mean value of $f$ taken around the boundary of a disc $D_r(a)$ centered at $a$ and contained in $B$. That's *really weird*.

Comment: The following is an example of what goes wrong with the straightforward generalization of the MVT to complex-valued functions: $f(x)=\exp(ix)$ satisfies $f(0)=f(2\pi)$, but $f'(x)$ is never equal to zero.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the mean value theorem.

Start with

$$y^k-x^k=(y-x)(y^{k-1}+xy^{k-2}+...+x^{k-2}y+x^{k-1})$$

so that

$$y^k-x^k-k(y-x)x^{k-1} = (y-x)\left[(y^{k-1}-x^{k-1})+x(y^{k-2}-x^{k-2})+...+x^{k-2}(y-x)\right]$$

and in absolute values, with $|x|<r$, $|y|<r<R$,

\begin{align*}
\left|y^k-x^k-k(y-x)x^{k-1}\right| 
&\le |y-x|^2\left((k-1)r^{k-2}+(k-2)r^{k-2}+...+r^{k-2}\right|\\
&=\frac{k(k-1)}2 |y-x|^2r^{k-2}
\end{align*}

Now define $g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty kc_k x^{k-1}$ and find a bound for $|f(y)-f(x)-(y-x)g(x)|$ that proves that $g(x)$ is the derivative of $f$ at $x$.